# flutter apps blank when I rotate portrait to landscape

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I have a flutter app which is basically a book with 210 pages created by a flutter page builder. But the problem is after 150 pages when I rotate it to portrait to Landscape its just blank. How can I solve these problems?

Comment: Do you have `DeviceOrientation` explicitly set in your `main()` function of the app?

Answer (score 0):

Setting the orientations you want explicitly in the app's 'main()` function could work...

```
void main() {
    WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
    SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([
        DeviceOrientation.portraitUp,
        DeviceOrientation.portraitDown,
        DeviceOrientation.landscapeLeft,
        DeviceOrientation.landscapeRight,
    ]);
    runApp(MyApp());
}
```